# Can't upload an image to Google Drive using Google Drive Api in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload an image to Google Drive using Google Drive Api in Swift. But getting the following error message:- 
**unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)
{"error":{"code":401,"message":"Login Required","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}]},"id":"gtl_3"}**

Her is my code -

```
      func uploadFileToDrive() {
        print("uploading Photo")
        let dateFormat  = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "'Quickstart Uploaded File ('EEEE MMMM d, YYYY h:mm a, zzz')"

        let file = GTLDriveFile()
        file.name = dateFormat.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        file.descriptionProperty = "Uploaded from Google Drive IOS"
        file.mimeType = "image/png"

        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

        // If array of path is empty the document folder not found
        guard urls.count == 0 else {
            let imageURL = urls.first!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("image.png")
            // Data object to fetch image data
            do {
                let imageData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL, options: NSDataReadingOptions())
                let uploadParameters = GTLUploadParameters(data: imageData, MIMEType: file.mimeType)
                let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesCreateWithObject(file, uploadParameters: uploadParameters) as GTLQueryDrive
                self.driveService.executeQuery(query, completionHandler:  { (ticket, insertedFile , error) -> Void in
                    let myFile = insertedFile as? GTLDriveFile

                    if error == nil {
                        print("File ID \(myFile?.identifier)")
                    } else {
                        print("An Error Occurred! \(error)")
                    }

                })
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

            return
        }
    }
```

Please help me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error is quite clear: you need to authenticate.

Comment: How do I authenticate uploading URL? @AlexandreCartapanis

Comment: I don't know ios, try googling "ios swift2 google-drive-sdk authenticate"

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreCartapanis

Comment: @DhimanRanjit Have you solve it your problem? Can you please share your code for uploading image?

Answer (score 0):

You need authentication to upload to Google Drive. The authentication process for using [Drive API with iOS](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/auth#register_your_application_in_the_console_name_short) is:

1. Create an oAuthclientID in GDC for your app.
2. Set the scopes.

   NSString scopes = `@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"`
   NSString *keychainItemName = @"My App";
   NSString *clientId = @"PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE";
3. Check for stored credentials.
4. Request authorization if necessary.
5. Handle the authentication response.

After authentication and authorization is finished, you can now [Upload in Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files#reading_files).